# EventLog & ConvertFrom-String

Tags: audit, auditing, audit-trail, audit-logging

i am trying to objectify the security event log by using the `ConvertFrom-String` PowerShell cmdlet, but am not able to work it out.

First i am getting the event/s from my DC.

```
$events = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $comp FilterHashtable @{logname='security';id=4727}
```

Next i define my template.

`$tmpl = @'
{Event:A security-enabled global group was created.}
Subject:
    Security ID:        S-1-5*
    {SubjectName:Account Name:      andrew}
    Account Domain:     DOMAIN
    Logon ID:       0x16D280EB
New Group:
    Security ID:        S-1-5*
    {GroupName:Group Name:      test1}
    Group Domain:       DOMAIN
Attributes:
    SAM Account Name:   test1
    SID History:        -
Additional Information:
    Privileges:     -
'@`

Finally i try to turn it into objects.

```
($events).message | ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $tmpl
```

But my output is only

`Event: A security-enabled global group was created.`

Instead, I want to get something like;

- Event: A security-enabled global group was created
- SubjectName: andrew
- GroupName: test1

And i would like this to be compatible to loop through many similar events to pull out the right bits??

Answer (score 1):

I posted the same question in the Microsoft forums and got an immediate answer, and so for those interested, here it is.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/42f8e6a3-4304-4215-b521-d611e3216e1c/eventlog-convertfromstring?forum=winserverpowershell